# Redirecting a /?p=xxx wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect a single Wordpress URL that is formatted like this: `www.bluewidgets.com/?p=123` to a clean URL on another domain. How can I do this via `.htaccess`? All of the tutorials I've seen say that I need to specify another part of the url, like `index.php`, before the query string, but my URL doesn't have one - it's just the domain and then the query string.

Comment: What you mean by "clean url"? www.bluewidgets.com/?p=123 has to be redirected to www.redwidgets.com/?p=123? Or www.bluewidgets.com/?p=123 to www.redwidgets.com/post/really-cool-widgets? Do the different domains posts have the same ids or the same url slugs? Do you want to redirect all old ids or just specific ones?:

Comment: I mean www.bluewidgets.com/?p=123 to www.redwidgets.com/post/really-cool-widgets

The different domains don't have any of the same elements anymore. I just want to redirect one particular URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just add to the header.php, before anything else:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['p'] == '123') {
    header('Location:http://www.yourotherdomain.com');
exit;
}
?>
```

I've done something similar in the past. It may not be pretty, but it works - I'd be interested to hear from more experienced PHP-ers whether it's a legitimate tactic.

Comment: Hi, I tried putting the code you gave into various parts of the header.php (above all code, above the <head> section, in the <head> section, but am getting this error (showing different lines depending on where I add it of course):

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home1/bluewidgets/public_html/foobar/wp-content/themes/scribblings/header.php on line 2

I don't mind using this method at all instead of htaccess, just having some trouble getting it working.

Comment: Change the first line to <?php  - notice no space and add ?> at the end and then try that.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! :D

And thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =p=123
RewriteRule ^$ /foo/bar? [L,R=301]
```

Or using *REQUEST_URI*:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/?p=123
RewriteRule ^$ /foo/bar? [L,R=301]
```

Note that the `RewriteCond` patterns begin with a `=` that identifies a lexicographical comparison instead of a regular expressions test. Additionally the empty query in *substitution* (denoted with `…?`) that will remove the originally requested query.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't wordpress already have built in URL prettyfication? Just out of curiosity why would you need to do this.

Aside from that, yes what you mention is how you'd do it via htaccess. Are you encountering an issue with this method?

Comment: The problem is that I have two domains: domain1.com and domain2.com.

I originally had my blog on domain1.com, then the actual name of my site became available to register so I registered domain2.com and made that my primary domain and parked domain1.com on top of it.

That particular post - domain1.com/?p=xxx  - has a paid post on it and the URL has to remain there for me to be paid monthly. However, I now want to separate domain1.com and domain2.com and use domain1.com for other purposes. So I need to implement a redirect from that domain1 post URL to the domain2 post URL

Comment: And what I mention seems to require that there be another bit to the URL, like /index.php?p=xxxx - as you see my URL does not have the index.php bit, just the /?p=xxxx so when trying that method it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

A standard 301 redirect is in the format (and would be at domain1):

```
Redirect 301 /filename.php http://domain2.com/filename.php
```

but I just tried that with default permalinks and it didn't work.

On domain1, you could rewrite the URL with the standard wordpress rewrite block, and then immediatly redirect it tp domain2. Messy, but it might work.

Comment: I tried the code you posted earlier, it doesn't seem to work with query strings. Not sure how to rewrite the URL the way you mean :S

Comment: Do you have wordpress at domain1? Or something else that uses mod_rewrite and might conflict with wordpress?

Comment: Both domain1 and domain2 are running two different Wordpress installations.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/ rather than get into your .htaccess files.